# Parse Json response with same key but different values using Jakson

Tags: java, android, json

This is my first response

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "place_id": 1234,
      "title": "unhelathy Food",
      "description": "Bad food is unhealthy",
      "contact_no": 7487474
    },
    {
      "place_id": 1234,
      "title": "Health Food",
      "description": "Good food is healthy",
      "contact_no": 7487474
    }
]
}
```

This is my second response which is almost the same

```
 {
   "data": {
   "place_id": 1234,
   "title": "unhelathy Food",
   "description": "Bad food is unhealthy",
   "contact_no": 7487474
 }
}
```

Do if you will see in 1st response data is `JsonArray`
and in second response data is Json Object

Below is my Class

```
public class UserResponseModel implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("data")
private UserModel userModel;
}
```

How Can I manage both `Object` and `Array` in same reference userModel

Comment: can you modify your response data ? As you can handle both the apects when you declare your " Data " as array.It can take single as well as multiple objects. And that would be the rite way of doing rather validating for both.

Comment: from a data model design POV, it make sense to return an array with one element in the second case as well